# What happens if I locally redefined a previously exported variable?

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I have a script called foo1.sh that does this:

```
export FOO=something
./foo2.sh
```

And also a foo2.sh written like this:

```
FOO=otherthings
echo $FOO
```

Is a local definition allowed to hide previously defined global variable? What will happen to `FOO` in foo2.sh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each environment gets a full copy of all environment variables. If you redefine the environment variable in a sub-shell, it will be redefined in that sub-shell and any shells that sub-shell spawns. However, it will not affect the parent shell.

If your `foo2.sh` is run in a separate sub-shell that the calling script is run in, redefining stuff won't affect the initial script. And, the way you executed `foo2.sh` is done in this way.

If you did this instead:

```
. ./foo2.sh
```

Then, `foo2.sh` is run in the current shell, and changing foo will affect the calling shell's value of `$FOO`

Here's an example:

### foo.sh

```
export FOO="BAR"
echo "FOO = $FOO"
./foo2.sh
echo "FOO = $FOO"
```

### foo2.sh

```
echo "In foo2: FOO = $FOO"
FOO="CHANGED!"
echo "In foo2: FOO = $FOO"
```

Here's what happens when I execute `foo.sh`:

```
$ ./foo.sh
FOO = BAR
In foo2: FOO = BAR
In foo2: FOO = CHANGED!
FOO = BAR
```

Notice that `$FOO` reverts to its old value once we're back in the calling shell script.

Answer (score 1):

`export`ing a shell variable means that it is *copied* into the environments of newly created subprocesses, including subshells.

An exported variable is not otherwise different from any other variable. The copy (which is implicitly exported for subshells) is just a copy; it has no relationship to the environment of the parent or sibling processes.

Comment: I know what export does. What I'm asking is, in this specific case, what value will `FOO` hold after I re-assign it in foo2.sh.

Comment: @RobertDailey: FOO in the subshell will be assigned a new value. No other FOO is affected. There is no such thing as a "global" FOO.

Answer (score 1):

An environment variable is simply a variable whose *initial* value is inherited from the process's parent and whose value is copied into the environment of any child processes. Otherwise, its value may be changed like any other variable.